# Change letter color of tableview if found searchbar text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I have search bar and table view. I can filter table view items based on search bar text. But I have to change found letter's color. For example if I write HE to search bar, I want to show HELLO in table view but the color of HE should different than LLO.

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Check out `NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `NSMutableAttributedString` for your concept, Here I tell the logic customize yourself where you need (must call in inside the cellForRow)

```
    lblcheck.text = "hello" // is the original text 
    lblcheck.textColor = UIColor.red // initally set the whole color for your text
    //Create mutable string from original one
    let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lblcheck.text!)
    //Fing range of the string you want to change colour
    //If you need to change colour in more that one place just repeat it
    let range: NSRange = (lblcheck.text! as NSString).range(of: "he", options: .caseInsensitive) //he in here use searchBar.text
    attString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white, range: range) // here set selection color what ever you typed
    //Add it to the label - notice its not text property but it's attributeText
    lblcheck.attributedText = attString
```

Answer (score 1):

Text color change can be done by using `NSAttributedString`. When you show your search results, in your `cellForRow` delegate method, get search string and replace the word in your `textView` with `NSAttributedString` version. You can change color for the specific string in your `NSAttributedString`.

This is the general idea without seeing any code.

Comment: thanks. i used NSAttributedString as you and anbu.kartnik said.